# Sonos API: Starting the playlist issue

Tags: sonos

Is it possible to say firmware to start playlist always in randomize order? I didn't fine any information in Sonos API documentation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If these are true playlists these are added to the Sonos queue for playback. On Sonos the queue can be in shuffle mode or not anything; added to the queue will then either be shuffled when you play it based on the queue state.  This is not something the music service can control.